# C descriptor for double on Linux

Tags: double

What is the Descriptor for double in C? When I use

```
printf("%d",x)
```

and `x` is a `double` variable it says a warning that it `%d expects an int argument, while x is double`.

Comment: Can't you just read the documentation for `printf()`?

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%f", x);
```

When `x` is a `double` variable.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a number of format specifiers for printf. Here are the basic ones :

```
%d  print an int argument in decimal
%ld print a long int argument in decimal
%c  print a character
%s  print a string
%f  print a float or double argument
%e  same as %f, but use exponential notation
%g  use %e or %f, whichever is better
%o  print an int argument in octal (base 8)
%x  print an int argument in hexadecimal (base 16)
%%  print a single %
```